# how to make background for all ios devices in all screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I created a Sprite Sheet with SpriteHelper. When I created a background in spritehelper (universal app), the picture size was 1920 x 1280. How to make backgrounds for all devices and all screens?

```
CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

  CCSpriteBatchNode *sprites_for_game;      
  sprites_for_game = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"sprite_UntitledSheet.png"];

  [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"sprite_UntitledSheet.plist"];
   [self addChild:sprites_for_game];
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"background"];
        sprite.position = ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2);
        [sprites_for_game addChild:sprite];
```

iPhone Retina 3.5 inch http://pixs.ru/showimage/Snimokekra_9096412_10672667.png

iPhone Retina 4.0 inch http://pixs.ru/showimage/Snimokekra_8101239_10672678.png

who can help me?
Thanks

Comment: ipad http://pixs.ru/showimage/Snimokekra_6722907_10672708.png                         
ipad petina     http://pixs.ru/showimage/Snimokekra_7539276_10672720.png

Answer (score 1):

Well, it comes down to two options.

**Option 1**: Scale the image to fit the screen with the scale property like `sprite.scale = 1.5f;`.  I would **NOT** recommend this as the image will look like garbage as you scale it up.

**Option 2**: Re-render the image at the higher resolutions and decide in your code which image to use based on your screen size.  This is what I would recommend doing for better quality.

Comment: @user3243304 Check out this posting on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771353/creating-ios-universal-app-how-to-detect-all-5-resolutions